# Stop inheriting permissions programatically

Tags: 2010, permissions, security

I want to set read permissions to some sharepoint groups to a list.

For existing sites I did it manually, Stop Inherit permissions. Then on groups I chose the groups and edited their permissions, which I set to Read only.

I want to do exactly the same but by using code. So when a new site is provisioned permissions are set this way by default.

```
private void SetReadAccessOnList(SPSite newSite, string groupName)
        {
            try
            {
                SPList WorkspaceAccessList = newSite.RootWeb.Lists["mylist"];
                newSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                WorkspaceAccessList.BreakRoleInheritance(true);                                
                using (SPWeb webSite = newSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPGroup group = webSite.Groups[groupName];
                    AssignReadPermissionsToList(webSite, WorkspaceAccessList, group, SPRoleType.Reader);
                }                   
                newSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.PortalLog.LogString("Error Site: :  {0} || {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(ex.ToString());
            }           
        }


        public static void AssignReadPermissionsToList(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject secObj, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
        {
            if (!secObj.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
            {
                secObj.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
            }
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
            SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
            roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
            secObj.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it like this:

```
public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject secObj, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
{
    if (!secObj.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
    {
        secObj.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
    }

    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

    secObj.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
}
```

secObj - SPList, SPListItem

obj - SPUser, SPGroup

About SPRoleType you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproletype%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: please check my updated code, will that make the trick or I am missing something else?+

Comment: Remove WorkspaceAccessList.BreakRoleInheritance(true); from your code.

Comment: how to get/set the spsecuruable object into a SPLIST?please help

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the permissions code to the WebProvisioned Event Reciever:

http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2010/10/07/how-to-attach-an-event-receiver-to-the-web-added-event-and-for-what-purpose/

And here is the code with which you can set custom permissions programmatically to a list or document library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535228.aspx

Comment: please check my updated code, will that make the trick or I am missing something else?

Comment: Yeah both functions should do the trick. If you get any errors, you can post them here.