# Constraints on viewing list items

Tags: list, permissions, groups, view

Suppose there's a `top-secret` list (inherits its restrictions from its parent) that contains records that were created earlier by different users. There are several groups with rights to administer, read, write-constrainted.

There is a group of authors of `top-secret` elements. `Author` can only create a 'secret'. But so called 'secret' item shouldn't be viewed by other participants of the group (`Authors`).

How do I make that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break role inheritance for an item in event receiver by 'top-secret' field value, then assigne permission for a user that is author of an item. How to break permission assignment and assigne a new one you can read in this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31941/stop-inheriting-permissions-programatically/31942#31942). In this case this item can see only author and Site Administrator.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But in my case I cannot do anything programmaticaly, there's only administrative part for me. Howcome I do this that way?

Comment: I do not think that you can use this approach whithout code... I think that you can create a [custom list view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-or-change-a-view-HA010021577.aspx). The main problem is that site owners and user with full permissions can create views, thus you should deny access to this possibility. You can do this by the [custom permission levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx).

Comment: I've found an article http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58. So I think it's what I need. The only thing I'm afraid is a lack of permissions in other groups. Any advice?

Comment: If you setup `Only their own` property, all items in lists will be secret for other users, except administrator (he can see all items)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Ahh. But there's said that lists managers are also to maintain the items? Can I as administrator give other groups the privilege?

Comment: In this approach the user can see all items (if he has full access to this list) or can see only their own. There is no more options. Thus this approach is not applicable in your case ((((